# Notifying if a plane has been found

Tags: python, python-3.x

The object is to notify if a plane was found or not.
The `aircraft_identifier` variable is a must. `cpl_id` and `target_no` are optional, only either of them can be applied at time not both, they are used for further identification if aircraft_identifier is not unique.

```
qo = 'squawk' or 'callsign'  # only these variants are possible
qo_squawk = '12345'
qo_callsign = 'AMAN3'
qo_cplId = '11'
qo_targetNo = '22'

def decision_making(aircraft_identifier, cpl_id=None, target_no=None):
    found_target = False

    if qo == 'callsign' or qo == 'squawk':
        if aircraft_identifier.isdigit():
            found_target = (aircraft_identifier == qo_squawk)
        else:
            found_target = (aircraft_identifier == qo_callsign)

        if found_target:
            if cpl_id:
                found_target = True if qo_cplId == cpl_id else False
            if target_no:
                found_target = True if qo_targetNo == target_no else False

            if found_target:
                print('Found target!')
                return

    print('plane not found in list!')


decision_making('AMAN3', '22')
```

Can this code be made simpler?

Comment: Some answers have suggested simplifications to the logic in this function. However, based on the wishy-washy name `decision_making()`, as well as the fact that the function doesn't return any useful value, I suspect that real gains would be made by changing the design of your entire program. I encourage you to ask another question containing more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- “only either can be used at a time not both” – nothing in the function enforces that at most one of these input parameters has been set. Something like this:

  ```
  if (cpl_id is not None) and (target_no is not None):
       raise ValueError("At most one of cpl_id and target_no should be supplied")
  ```

  would ensure that at most one of them can be specified by the user.
- You have several lines of the form

  ```
  found_target = foo == bar
  ```

  I’d put some parentheses around the condition, because I think it makes it easier to read:

  ```
  found_target = (foo == bar)
  ```

  Later in the function you have two lines of the form

  ```
  found_target = True if foo == bar else False
  ```

  which can be reduced to the construction above.
- You have one function that does both business logic (checking whether the plane is correct) and doing some work (printing to screen). You should really separate these two – this function should return True/False, and then the caller should handle printing an appropriate message.
- This line:

  ```
  if qo == 'callsign' or qo == 'squawk':
  ```

  is a bit unwieldy because you have to add an extra `or` statement every time you add a new possibility for qo. Better to do something like:

  ```
  if qo in ['callsign', 'squawk']:
  ```

  which is easy to extend with more values.

  (Although it's not clear why you're doing this check at all, given that qo will always be `squawk` in the function as defined.)
- There are no comments or docstrings. I don’t know anything about planes, so I just have to trust that the conditionals are correct. It would be good to provide some explanation of what this all means – for example, what’s a CPL ID, or what is the qo_ prefix for?

Comment: This is a simplified version of production code, I should not have hardcoded the variables above found_target, it was added there to give an example for input. Of course in reality the function would return something!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I modified my code partly according to your comments.

Comment: My concern is that I'm probably missing a check if both `cpl_id` and `target_no` var are set, that should not be allowed.
Also I'm concerned with my last `if found_target:` branch, if I'm missing something.